# grub2の脆弱性に対する外部からの攻撃可能性について

Tags: linux, security, grub

https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2022-28733

現在、上記grub2の脆弱性について影響調査を進めております。
ページの内容をみたところ、ipv4パケット操作に関する脆弱性であることや、attack vectorがNetworkとなっておることから、外部から攻撃が可能なものと読み取っております。

とはいえ、linux上にデプロイされているwebサイトにアクセスする一般ユーザーが、grub2のようなOSレイヤに近しい脆弱性に対し、攻撃を仕掛けるのは難しそうな印象を受けるのですが、そこらへんは関係なく攻撃は可能なものなのでしょうか？、、、

Comment: > 攻撃を仕掛けるのは難しそうな印象 … ほとんど乗っ取った状態でないと攻撃できないのなら攻撃仕掛けるのは「難しい」と言えるけど, ブートローダー動いてる時に IPv4パケット送るのはタイミングの問題だけでは？ あと, 一般ユーザーが豹変して攻撃しかけるのではなく たいていは攻撃する目的の人が攻撃します